# MS SQL - Complex cross join view to display ratecard for product groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I am hoping someone can help.

I have 4 tables as listed below.

Table **Ratecard** holds a lists of ratecards
Table **Client** holds a list of clients
Table **ProductRatecardGroup** holds a list of groups which products belong to
Table **RatecardProductGroupClientRatecard** is a lookup table which determines which ratecard applies to certain product groups for a given client.

I need to create a view which displays this information.  If a client has no entries in the **RatecardGroupClient** table then the default ratecard ID is displayed (in this case, "6").

The tables are structured as below:

**Client**
ClientId
ClientName

**ProductRatecardGroup**
ProductRatecardGroupId PK
RatecardGroupName

**Ratecard**
RatecardId PK 
RatecardName

**RatecardProductGroupClientRatecard**
RatecardProductGroupClientRatecardId PK 
ClientId FK
ProductRatecardGroupId FK 
RatecardId FK

Imagine I have 2 clients and 5 ratecard product groups...

The RatecardProductGroupClientRatecard table could be completely empty and I should still get 10 records (this would be the standard ratecard for each product group for each client).

If I have entries in the RatecardProductGroupClientRatecard table for one client only, I should still get 10 records (with the user specified ratecard overriding the default).

I have tried the following

```html
SELECT DISTINCT
c.ClientId, 
prg.ProductRatecardGroupId, 
prg.ProductRatecardGroupName,
ISNULL(p.RatecardId,(SELECT RatecardId FROM Ratecard WHERE RatecardId = (SELECT RatecardDefaultRatecardId From Configuration))) AS 'RatecardId',
ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50),p.DateAdded), 'n/a') as 'DateAdded',
ISNULL((e.Firstname + ' ' + e.Surname),'n/a') as 'EmployeeName'
FROM

Client c 
LEFT JOIN ProductRatecardGroupClientRatecard prgcr ON 1 = 1
CROSS JOIN ProductRatecardGroup prg
LEFT JOIN ProductRatecardGroupClientRatecard p ON 
p.ClientId = c.ClientId AND 
p.ClientId = prgcr.ClientId AND prg.ProductRatecardGroupId = p.ProductRatecardGroupId AND p.Enabled = 1
LEFT JOIN Employee e ON p.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
```

This gives me the following:

```html
+------+---+-------------+----+---------------------+------------+
| 2093 | 1 | Cameras     |  6 | n/a                 | n/a        |
| 2093 | 1 | Cameras     | 15 | Feb 20 2019  3:32PM | John Smith |
| 2093 | 2 | Accessories |  6 | n/a                 | n/a        |
| 2093 | 2 | Accessories | 11 | Feb 20 2019  3:32PM | John Smith |
| 2093 | 3 | Misc        |  6 | n/a                 | n/a        |
| 2093 | 3 | Misc        | 10 | Feb 20 2019  3:51PM | John Smith |
+------+---+-------------+----+---------------------+------------+
```

This nearly works but duplicates the entries, showing both the standard ratecard and the client specific ratecard.

Could anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Many thanks in advance.

I solved this problem using the below code:

```html
SELECT * FROM 
(
 SELECT a.*,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.ClientId) AS AutoId,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ClientId, a.ProductRatecardGroupId ORDER BY a.CustomId DESC) AS rn
 FROM
 (
 SELECT DISTINCT
 c.ClientId, 
 prg.ProductRatecardGroupId, 
 prg.ProductRatecardGroupName,
 ISNULL(p.RatecardId,(SELECT RatecardId FROM Ratecard WHERE RatecardId = (SELECT RatecardDefaultRatecardId From Configuration))) AS 'RatecardId',
 ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50),p.DateAdded), 'n/a') as 'DateAdded',
 ISNULL((e.Firstname + ' ' + e.Surname),'n/a') as 'EmployeeName',
 p.RatecardId as 'CustomId'
 FROM

 Client c 
 LEFT JOIN ProductRatecardGroupClientRatecard prgcr ON 1 = 1
 CROSS JOIN ProductRatecardGroup prg
 LEFT JOIN ProductRatecardGroupClientRatecard p ON 
 p.ClientId = c.ClientId AND 
 p.ClientId = prgcr.ClientId AND prg.ProductRatecardGroupId = p.ProductRatecardGroupId AND p.Enabled = 1
 LEFT JOIN Employee e ON p.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
 ) a
)
b
WHERE b.rn = 1
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help here, along with the attempt(s) you've already made or showing us what research you've done. Thanks.

Comment: Many apologies.  Have added the code and data I have so far.

Comment: I don't see any duplicates there. Perhaps you can share the table structure (create table statements) and sample data (insert statements) along with the desired output.

Comment: If you don't want both client and standard, then which one do you want?

Comment: If there is no record for ProductRatecardGroupClientRatecard for the given client (2093) then it should display the default ratecard for that group (ID 6). In the data above, it is displaying both the default ratecard and the ratecard I have added for that particular client.

Comment: I have solved this using the code updated above.